# If people didn’t have a moral sense, would we still have enforced cultural moral codes?

Tags: ethics, metaethics

Diverse, contradictory, and bizarre as they are, people commonly feel that everyone ought to conform to their culture’s moral norms and even feel violators deserve punishment, though perhaps that might be just social disapproval. Cultural moral norms have an emotional motivating force grounded in our biology.

What if our evolutionary history somehow missed acquiring this biology? Would we still have codes of conduct we would recognize as cultural moralities?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by an internal "moral sense". I see only human beings who are dominant stepping into a form of authority. In beast we call this built in mindset the "Alpha male". Humans are like the beast in this regard. That is, this is the beast or person who feels they are Divine sent to automatically be in charge. This is your cultural morality unless you can demonstrate other wise.

Comment: Since moral norms play a functional role they'd still have to be enforced, if not through emotions then through something else. Even as is, we do not rely on emotions alone. Deterrence by punishments has a rational component to it, and locking up those who do not comply weeds them out from the general population.

Comment: Is this not a self-defeating question? If we were unable to observe something, would we observe it? I suspect you may be relying on a particular definition of morals (e.g. collective vs convention vs personal) but the question doesn't quite make that clear.

Comment: Was there a specific incident or contemporary issue that brought this question to mind?

Comment: Mark Andrews, no specific incident brought this question to mind. It was more a gradual process of understanding that our moral judgments and cultural moral codes are best explained as solutions to cooperation dilemmas that are innate to our physical universe. That said, understanding the shameful origins of how 'moral' norms came to exist such as "women must be submissive to men" and "homosexuality is evil" when they are such disfunctional moral norms has encouraged me to think there is something culturally useful to say on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

As Protagoras explained to Socrates, and modern science confirms, people have a moral sense because it enables them to cooperate in groups. Imagine intelligent beings without a moral sense who needed to sustainably obtain the benefits of cooperation in order to achieve shared goals. They could do this by agreeing to enforce ‘moral’ codes regarding fairness, not killing, stealing, or lying, and “Doing to others as you would have them do to you” to initiate the most powerful cooperation strategy known, indirect reciprocity.

If morality is not dependent on our moral sense, then evolutionary debunking arguments such as Sharon Street’s and "morality as emotivism" need re-examination.

Comment: Beast can cooperate in groups as well so I see no distinction between  beast being led or humans being led by an Alpha male. In your interpretation do all members have equal status?  If not, why dont they?  How is this distinct from just bullying by an alpha male. Let's be clear most bullies will get physical to get there way. This way the subs will fall in line to whatever the alpha wants

Comment: Solitary animals still have some sense of moral code even if they do not need to cooperate. E.g. don't (usually) kill your own kind, (as a mother) protect your children with your life.

Comment: @ Frank Hubeny     1) Curry, O. S., et al (2018). Is It Good to Cooperate? Testing the Theory of Morality-as-Cooperation in 60 Societies https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/full/10.1086/701478      2) Harms, W., Skyrms, B. (2010) Evolution of Moral Norms.  Oxford Handbook on the Philosophy of Biology      3) Sloan, M.L. (2018) A Universal Principle Within Morality’s Ultimate Source  https://evolution-institute.org/a-universal-principle-within-moralitys-ultimate-source/     4) Tomasello, M., & Vaish, A. (2013). Origins of Human Cooperation and Morality. Annual Review of Psychology,

Comment: @Conifold Right, they would have to be enforced by something else if we had no moral sense. Enforcement by rule of law should be possible or perhaps a form of moral contractualism with deterrence for violators.

Comment: @Logikal Our internal moral sense is the source of our intuitive moral judgements. These judgments are triggered by cross-cultural universal circumstances (https://moralfoundations.org/) which in turn trigger motivating emotions (Haidt, J. 2003. The moral emotions. In Handbook of affective sciences) for elements of cooperation strategies.

Comment: @Flater We can observe the benefits of cooperation and the strategies that solve cooperation dilemmas that prevent accessing those benefits. Encoding those strategies into cultural norms and, as part of those strategies, punishing violators would reproduce the function of moral codes for beings without a moral sense who, nevertheless, desired to obtain the benefits of cooperation.

Comment: @Flater From genetic and science of morality perspectives, kin altruism is a cooperation strategy even though we don’t commonly think of kin altruism that way. A useful way to distinguish a ‘moral’ behavior is if violators of the relevant norm are commonly thought to deserve punishment. A mother bear that has no motivation to defend her cub might be thought mentally ill, but not immoral.

Comment: The terminology is problematic. Is there another way to phrase what you mean? There are many social fields that think morality is a hoax and some say there is none whatsoever. Popular opinion also suggest there is no morality period, it just all opinions. How can we have a moral sense if morality does not exist or what happens to the moral sense if morality were just opinions? Intuitive sense can usually be described as given by a diety but that might be a other topic. That is our creator installed a sixth sense what you are calling a moral sense. The wording is going to be trouble later on

Comment: @Logikal Our moral sense is a bit of biology people have that triggers emotions such as empathy, gratitude, loyalty, righteous indignation, guilt, and shame. If these feelings are foreign to you (as they are to perhaps 1% of men), I feel bad for your loss. Our moral sense exists because it motivated increased cooperation for our ancestors and, by doing so, gave them a reproductive fitness advantage.

Comment: Are you suggesting that moral sense is built in us?  If moral sense is built in then what if the idea morality is subjective or the idea there is no such thing as morality? Either way I see a problem with the terminology as moral sense. Pro life arguments say abortion is always murder and thus immoral.  Are they using a moral sense? Seems to me that is not instilled in us but that value is taught. Do we have to think about moral sense? It sounds like you express it is automatic and NOT learned. If moral truth values are learned then how do we have a built in mechanism?

Comment: @Logikal If you are really interested, you might have a look at the references I supplied to Frank Hubeny above.

Comment: Firstly, it would be better to build the sources into the body of the answer. Comments may vanquish in chat rooms or disappear for other reasons. Secondly, even better would be a short synopsis of the outcomes/theses of each study. Thirdly, I would take Haidt out of the equation. IIRC he is often criticised for begging the question and lacking critical evaluation. Last but not least: As far as I am aware of, Tomasello argues for the evolutionary development of *shared intentionality*. From that, it is quite a leap to "moral sense". I cannot comment on the other sources, though.

Comment: @Philip Klöcking  So far as I know, Haidt’s (and his coworker’s) data supporting the existence of a biological moral sense is sound science. It is Haidt’s conclusions about this data that are problematic and even wrong in my view. 
I am always surprised by people who question if we have a biological moral sense. To me, emotions such as empathy, gratitude, loyalty, guilt, and anger at unfairness to others are self-evident proof that I, and all who share these emotions, have a moral sense.